# Set of natural representatives/quotient group confusion

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is really annoying but I still can't seem to really understand quotient groups to save my life. We have a practice problem that says give the natural representative of

$\mathbb Z[i]/(3)$ i.e the Guassian integers/(3). I understand on some intuitive level that this is effectively $a+bi$ with $a$ and $b$ mod 3 so it should $1+0i$, $2+0i$, $1+1i$, etc. But I don't understand using the traditional definition as given here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group#Definition

Shouldn't it be the set $\{a(3)\mid a \in \mathbb Z[i]\}$?  Which would effectively be $a+bi$ with $a$ and $b$ simply as multiples of 3?

Answer (score 2):

That wikipedia article is using multiplication as the operation, but here the operation is addition so the quotient is
$$\{a + (3) \ | \ a \in \mathbb Z[i]\}$$
and your intuition for what the representatives for the various cosets should be is correct.

Comment: Sorry this might be the dumbest question of all time, but how do you know the operation is addition? Couldn't you have the Guassian integers under multiplication as well?

Comment: The way I learned it in my first modern algebra course was that, when you have a group that contains an element *without* a multiplicative inverse then the group clearly can't be multiplicative. When working with subsets of $\Bbb C$ (or $\Bbb R$) that include $0$ then $0$ does not have a multiplicative inverse (where 1 is the mult. identity) so they must be additive groups. If you have a group like $\Bbb R -\{0\}$ then you assume the group is multiplicative (because every element will have a multiplicative inverse). In your group, $0(3) = 0$ would have been in the group.

Comment: Though I should say I've only taken one semester of abstract algebra so it probably gets more complicated than this.

Comment: @RogerTynes: It is part of the *definition* of an ideal that it's a subgroup of the **additive** structure of the ring.  It's also part of the *definition* of a quotient ring that the quotient is taken using the additive structure.  Plus what andraiamatrix says is correct, nonzero rings are not groups under multiplication because $0$ doesn't have a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: I appreciate both your comments. I see Andriamatrix's point, but I justwant to clarify your point Jim. Quotient rings are always taken using the additive operation?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

$(3)$ is $\{3a \mid a\in\mathbb Z[i]\}$, as you describe. $\mathbb Z[i]/(3)$ is the quotient of $\mathbb Z[i]$ by this ideal, i.e. we treat $(3)$ as $0$. As you describe, the elements of this are $1+0i$, $2+0i$, $1+1i$, etc. For example,

$$(1 + 0i) + (2 + 1i) = 3 + 1i = \underbrace{(3+0i)}_{\in(3)} + (0 + 1i) \equiv 0 + 1i \mod 3$$

So we'd write $1 + (2 + i) = i$ in $\mathbb Z[i]/(3)$.

Comment: I guess what's confusing me is that I was trying to represent this via multiplication? How do you know the operation is addition?

Comment: I think you can show it is under addition, because, e.g., the class 1+i is equivalent to, say, 4+4i. This is because the differences 4-1=3, and 4i-i=3i are in the ideal of multiples of 3. Remember that ideals are _additive_ subgroups. See here:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(ring_theory) in the last line on the "Properties" section of the post.